# UILabel with Link with more than one line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

i want to use UILabel with link.

for that i am using IFTweetLabel which is finding any link and showing a line under it and it is clickable.

but if a string is big then only first line is getting hyperlink instead of complete URL.

as an issue with https://github.com/clawoo/IFTweetLabel/issues/3.

so is there any other option for it , or other library ?

Comment: u can use UItextView for detecting and opening links..why dont u use it?

Comment: but i think , by doing this app is going to reject.

Comment: App won't get reject by using `UITextView`... It is the controller and linkDetector property is provided by Apple itself

Comment: Have you got the solution? Because I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to import RegexKitLite framework. Go through this link. Surely this will help you. It gives same thing as you want.

http://furbo.org/stuff/FancyLabel_1.0.zip

Comment: Please add some more detail here.  How does linking to a zip file resolve the authors problem?  If it's a library that you are linking to, please provide a suggestion on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would like to suggest is

Use `UITextView` with editing property as **NO** and it will automatically detect all the links separately similar like the one you need.

```
textview.editable = NO;
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

If you still want to go with UILabel then

You can achieve this by using [`NSArrtibutedStrings`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) — but I would recommend to use some wrapper around this C-functions. I like [`OHAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

The demo included shows exactly, how hyperlinks can be handled.

Comment: i use it with NSAttributedStr and it is working fine , but there is one issue it is not considering ? , like if i wirte "http://www.abc.com/a.asp?abc" then it is not taking string "?abc"

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20)  project.

Comment: actually i have seen code of Fancy Label , it is also using "IFTweetLabel"

Answer (score 0):

what is the reason for not using `UITextView`..there is link detection property for `UITextView`.Your app is not going to get rejected